# What is your favourite asychronous pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to get my head around the CCR as a Asynchronous programming model.  In the past i've used the standard begin/end methods.  I primary develop in VB.net and have been looking with longing at the Yield/Enumerator tricks.

What is your favourite asychronous pattern?

Answer (score 2):

The [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Reaching for my Head-First Design Patterns Book...

Answer (score 1):

[Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

F# [async workflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/10/11/introducing-f-asynchronous-workflows.aspx), or similar stuff from other .NET languages using LINQ as in

http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/10/15/functional-c-implementing-async-computations-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Producer-consumer pattern

http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3023

http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/producer_consumer1.html

Answer (score 0):

[Dataflow programming model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming) and its most interesting special case, [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)